# Make <th> clickable: Setting a <a> element inside the <th> on 100% width & height

Tags: css

I have a css problem that I'm stuck on.. I can't get my clickable header links to get a 100% height; without using javascript.

I've tried many things I've found while googling but none of them fixed my problem.

I get this result:

[alt text http://thomasstock.net/css100percent.jpg](http://thomasstock.net/css100percent.jpg)

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">header 1</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">some very very very very very very very very very long header 2</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    cell a1
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell a2
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell a3
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    cell b1
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell b2
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell b3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

With this css:

```
table
{
    width: 300px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td
{
    border: solid 1px;
}

th a
{
    background-color: Fuchsia;

    /* Making the headerlinks 100% width */
    width:100%;
    float:left;

    /* Making the headerlinks 100% height ??? */
    height: 100%; /* doesnt work! */
    min-height:100%;
}
tr
{
    height:100%;
}
```

[download this code here](http://thomasstock.net/css100percent.zip)

**=> How do I make the headers turn completely pink & clickable?** (without using javascript?)

Answer (score 14):

You have to display the `a` inside the `th`s as a [block-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes):

```
th a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This allows me to use the 100% width without having to set float: left, but it doesn't seem to fix the 100% height..

Comment: You need to give the TH elements a specific height. Because otherwise the TH’s height depends on the height of its children. And on the other hand children’s heights depend on their containing boxes, hence the TH elements.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `display:block` on your links in the headers. height:width attributes are ignored on inline elements;

```
th a
{
    display:block;
    background-color: Fuchsia;

    /* Making the headerlinks 100% width */
    width:100%;

    /* Making the headerlinks 100% height ??? */
    height: 100%;
}
```

Edit:
Forgot to mention that for 100% height to work, the parent needs to have a height specified, e.g.

```
th 
{
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: This allows me to use the 100% width without having to set float: left, but it doesn't seem to fix the 100% height..

Comment: @ edit: yes indeed, the parent needs the specific height. But I was hoping for a solution where that wasn't needed. 
Oh well, I'll just use this for javascript-disabled people and add a click event on the TH in javascript for the other 96% of the visitors :-)

Comment: sounds like a good plan. Prototype or JQuery are good for making that easy on the JS side. Just loop through the children, find the largest height, and set all children to share that height. Just be careful when setting the heights that browser resizing is taken into account. You can use the onresize event (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onresize.asp) to determine when that should happen.

Comment: Thomas...if the answer was satisfactory...then 'select' the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not plausible, but in some cases setting

```
th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Gets rid of the problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You could set an arbitrary height to each link to quite long: (6em maybe?) then set a max height on the table cell `th`'s to something shorter: (3em?) with an overflow hidden. This way all the links will be taller than the table cell is high but chopped off by the overflow hidden - they should all be pink and clickable. Make sure you set a `display:relative;` on the `th`'s otherwise old versions of IE won't chop off any overflow. Good luck :)